# Insert year from from a number indicater in a SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to be able to populate the year in my Table `Documents` now the the only place were the year is kept is in my `File_Name` column, but the draw back is that its not the entire year format.

**For example**

```
File_Name
11.NR012546
11.NR021548
11.NR021236
09.02154664
```

**Breakdown of data**

`11. = Year`

```
NR012546 = Document number
```

Now, I need to take this year identifier and populate it in a column I created in my SQL Column called `YEAR` the format need to show `YYYYY`

** Update Statement **

```
File_Name    |  YEAR
11.NR012546  |  2011
11.NR021548  |  2011
11.NR021236  |  2011
09.02154664  |  2009
```

How would I go about this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your FileName format is fixed for all then use LEFT function to retrieve number from File Name and bind  with '20'

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (NAME VARCHAR(30),YEAR NUMERIC)
INSERT INTO @T(NAME) VALUES('11.NR012546'),('11.NR021548'),('11.NR021236'),('09.02154664')

UPDATE t
SET YEAR=CAST('20'+LEFT(NAME,2) AS NUMERIC)
FROM @T t
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
11.NR012546 2011
11.NR021548 2011
11.NR021236 2011
09.02154664 2009
```

Comment: Hi @JaydipJ, thank you for your response, I however need to insert the result into the same table in column Year.

Comment: The year column is numeric field and only allows for 4 characters